# Let X be a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let X be a random variable such that X $\leq \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\forall x < \alpha,: P(X \leq x) \leq \frac{\alpha-EX}{\alpha -x}$. (Hint: Use Chebyshev's inequality).

We're stuck on this question, this is the approach we took:

Let $y=\alpha-x$, as $ x \leq \alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow x-\alpha \leq 0 \rightarrow \alpha-x \geq 0 \rightarrow y \geq 0. \rightarrow y$ is non-negative r.v. Using chebyshev's inequality, $P(y \geq \alpha -x) \leq \frac{E(y)}{\alpha-x} \rightarrow P(\alpha -x \geq a-x) \leq \frac{E(\alpha -x)}{\alpha -x}$
$\rightarrow P(X \leq x) \leq \frac{\alpha-E(x)}{\alpha -x}.$

Comment: Why are you stuck? Isnt this a solution?

Comment: I think your mistake is that instead of $y=\alpha -x$ you need $Y = \alpha - X$ (to stress that they are random variables). So the second last inequality will be $P(\alpha - X \ge \alpha -x) \le \frac{E(\alpha - X)}{\alpha -x}$ and the result you want follows from linearity of expected value.

Comment: we we thought we were stuck but by the looks of it we went on the right direction right?